Как соединить две виртуальных сети, которые работают на разных серверах
Есть сеть Zerotier с адресами ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх и есть сеть Hamachi с адресами ууу.ууу.ууу.ууу
Сервер мой подключен и к той и к другой сети. Как сделать так, что бы устройства с одной сети пинговались с устройствами с другой сети?
Пробовал сделать мост - бесполезно.
